# How to capture unhandled task exception website wide asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling, webforms, unhandled-exception

I have a asp.net web application web forms project

I use below code in Global.asax file

```
    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
    if (Server.GetLastError() != null)
        if (Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException() != null)
        {
                          Exception objErr = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();    

        }
}
```

However this code is not capturing inside task happened errors

For example

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gg(); // this one is captured

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { gg(); }); //this one is not captured
    }
    private void gg()
    {
        string asdasdas = "asd";
        Convert.ToInt32(asdasdas);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Application_Error` can't catch exceptions outside of ASP.NET pipeline. So you need to use an `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event handler for that.

Comment: How do i add that to the asp.net website? i have found answer for c# WPF application but couldnt find for asp.net website webforms application @DmytroMukalov

Comment: See [there](https://mlichtenberg.wordpress.com/2011/09/19/catching-unhandled-exceptions-in-asp-net/)